# How to make the background of TextField rectangular box shape?

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried making `Container` widget with rectangle shape in `TextField`. It doesn't show my text inside container. Rather the box shape comes above `TextField`.

Here's my code:

```
 new Container(
            height: 10.0,
            width: 20.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                border: new Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
            child: new TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: '1',
                border: InputBorder.none,

              ),
            ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just remove the `height` and `width` property of the container.

Example:

```
   new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        border: new Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: new TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          hintText: '1',
          border: InputBorder.none,

        ),
      ),
    )
```

or else just specify the `border` property of `InputDecoration` like

```
new TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: '1',
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            const Radius.circular(0.0),
          ),
          borderSide: new BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Without height width Container isn't working. Maybe because it's inside `Row`.  Later one worked. But `TextField` showing extra padding inside. How can I remove that?

Comment: Try specifying `width` of container. Or just wrap `TextField` in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget. Can you share some code or atleast visual ref of what you are trying to achive? And do accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: An input field with rectangle shape background like this goo.gl/noQYjF I've kept the `TextField` inside a `Container` which has same width and height. For width it's taking perfect measurement but for height it's not showing perfect measurement.

Comment: What do you mean by not taking perfect measurement? May I know what height and width values you have specified? Moreover, why a `Row` widget for only one `TextField`?

Comment: Just wrap all the `Container` containing the `TextField` in a `Flexible` widget. That should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166393/discussion-between-hemanth-raj-and-farwa).

Answer (score 7):

```
         TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Email',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                ),
              ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true, // <- this is required.
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: kStadiumBorderRadius,
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
    ),
  ),
);
```